# php variables seems to be the same but they are not identical

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 php variables:

```
$account_name

$my
```

If I use function:

`var_dump($account_name);`

I get:

`string(192) "admin"`

`$account_name` is displayed like a link to account name

If I use function:

`var_dump($my);`

I get:

`string(5) "admin"`

How can I change variable `$account_name` that return my only "admin" String.

I have problem because if I use `$account_name` in SQL query nothing happens but if I use `$my` it works.

Comment: Why not just use $my in your queries?

Comment: Where is the code where you assign the value to the variable?

Comment: Use [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the links.

Answer (score 3):

It might be the case that your $account_name contains html tags. Since you are viewing it in browser, it is processed as html. You need to extract the value from those tags.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617515/php-empty-string-of-length-32) post.

Try:

```
$account_name = strip_tags($account_name);
```

[strip_tags reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your string contains non readable characters.
Try to strip the string using this example:

```
var_dump(preg_replace("/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/", '', $account_name));
```

If it works it should return: `string(5) "admin"`

Comment: Nice one. But you should mention that this works with ascii user names only.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting your variables?

If you're getting it from a form like this:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <button>click me</button>
</form>
```

you should simply collect the value of the input extracting the value in php

`<?php
  $account_name = $_GET["username"];
  echo $account_name;
?>`

In some cases you might want to strip the variables strip($_GET["username"]); to remove spaces before and after the string